# How to use re.search to find multiple strings?

Tags: python, regex, full-text-search

I'm trying to check if a certain line in many different text documents equals one of many different strings. To goal here is to classify those documents and then parse them according to that classification.

In my text editor I can use regex to search for:

```regex
(?:^kärnten\n|^steiermark|^graz\n|^madrid\n|^oststeirer\n|^weiz\n|^berlin\n|^lavanttal\n|^villach\n|^osttirol\n|^oberkärnten\n|^klagenfurt\n|^weststeiermark\n|^südsteiermark\n|^südoststeiermark\n|^murtal\n|^mürztal\n|^graz\n|^ennstal\n|^frankreich\n|^österreich\n|^dänemark\n|^polen\n|^großbritannien\n|^italien\n|^hitzendorf\n|^osttirol\n|^slowenien\n|^feldkirchen\n|^völkermarkt\n|^wien\n|^warschau\n|^mailand\n|^mainz\n|^leoben\n|^bleiburg\n|^brüssel\n|^bad radkersburg\n|^london\n|^lienz\n|^liezen\n|^hartberg\n|^ilztal|^pöllau\n|^lobmingtal\n)
```

But if I try to use this in an if statement in python I keep getting syntax errors for any way I tried it.

My current version is this:

```py
if re.search('(^kärnten\n|^steiermark|^graz\n|^madrid\n|^oststeirer\n|^weiz\n|^berlin\n|^lavanttal\n|^villach\n|^osttirol\n|^oberkärnten\n|^klagenfurt\n|^weststeiermark\n|^südsteiermark\n|^südoststeiermark\n|^murtal\n|^mürztal\n|^graz\n|^ennstal\n|^frankreich\n|^österreich\n|^dänemark\n|^polen\n|^großbritannien\n|^italien\n|^hitzendorf\n|^osttirol\n|^slowenien\n|^feldkirchen\n|^völkermarkt\n|^wien\n|^warschau\n|^mailand\n|^mainz\n|^leoben\n|^bleiburg\n|^brüssel\n|^bad radkersburg\n|^london\n|^lienz\n|^liezen\n|^hartberg\n|^ilztal|^pöllau\n|^lobmingtal\n)', article_lines[5].lower()replace('´','')):
        no_author = True
```

I saw that a possible solution is using a for loop and putting the different strings into a list, but as this would require some extra steps I'd prefer to do it as I tried if possible.

Comment: You have a dot missing before `replace`. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean? That the typo was the only problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include what the error is. Your problem is probably just a typo:

```
if re.search('(^kärnten\n|^steiermark|^graz\n|^madrid\n|^oststeirer\n|^weiz\n|^berlin\n|^lavanttal\n|^villach\n|^osttirol\n|^oberkärnten\n|^klagenfurt\n|^weststeiermark\n|^südsteiermark\n|^südoststeiermark\n|^murtal\n|^mürztal\n|^graz\n|^ennstal\n|^frankreich\n|^österreich\n|^dänemark\n|^polen\n|^großbritannien\n|^italien\n|^hitzendorf\n|^osttirol\n|^slowenien\n|^feldkirchen\n|^völkermarkt\n|^wien\n|^warschau\n|^mailand\n|^mainz\n|^leoben\n|^bleiburg\n|^brüssel\n|^bad radkersburg\n|^london\n|^lienz\n|^liezen\n|^hartberg\n|^ilztal|^pöllau\n|^lobmingtal\n)', article_lines[5].lower().replace('´','')):
        no_author = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll improve my next question. And yes a typo it was, had a dot missing before replace.